# Phase Portaits in Dynamical Sytems

Tags: dynamical-systems, jacobian

Searching for some help with trying to sketch the phase portrait for the system,

$$\ddot{x}=ax-x^2$$

for values of $a=0$, $a<0$, $a>0$.

How can I set up the Jacobian matrices and sketch the phase portrait of this system?

$\dot{x}=y$
$\dot{y}=ax-x^2$

then,

$y=0$
$x=0$
$x=a$

Comment: @Moo would this be the Jacobian? $$J=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\a-2x & 0\end{array}\right],$$ and if so then how would I evaluate?

Comment: @Moo okay thanks, so how would I evaluate for my critical points? being y=0,x=0,x=a

Comment: $$J(0,0)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\a & 0\end{array}\right],$$

Comment: $$J(a,0)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\-a & 0\end{array}\right],$$

Comment: I am just a little confused on how you calculated the Eigen values

Comment: Your question seems to be how one computes the eigenvalues of some matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\u&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Well, simply compute the characteristic polynomial $$\chi_M(x)=\det(xI-M)=x^2-u$$ and note that, if $u>0$, the roots are $\pm\sqrt{u}$ while if $u<0$ they are $\pm i\sqrt{-u}$. As you probably know, the first case signals that the fixed point is a saddle while the second case signals a center. End of story?

Comment: Please [edit] pertinent information into the question itself. Also, if you have an answer post it as **an answer**.

Comment: @Did so that is the Eigen vectors for J(0,0) would the Eigen vectors for J(a,0) be $+-\sqrt{-a}$

Comment: Whether $J(0,0)$ has complex eigenvalues and $J(a,0)$ has real eigenvalues, or the other way round, depends on the sign of $a$. My first comment allows you to decide which is which.